# How to return values in a new thread?

Tags: java, sql, multithreading

I have this piece of code and I want to return the value of, "sql" in a new thread so this query sends/fetches info from the database fast and not on the main thread. If I make a new thread and initialize a string with the sql and then return it out side of the thread, it returns null. Is there anyway I can return sql in a new thread without it being null? Thanks.

```
public String getCurrentG(final String username) {




            Sql2o sql2o = new Sql2o(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            String sql = "SELECT CurrentGuild FROM Players WHERE Username='" + username + "'";

            try (Connection con = sql2o.open()) {
              return con.createQuery(sql).executeScalar(String.class);
            }


        }
```

Comment: You can't *return* the information. You *can* accept a lambda (in Java 8) or interface-typed object with a method that you'll call back when the information is available.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking for.  Are you asking for how to return a value from a `Thread` to your main execution block, or are you asking how to initialize a `Thread` with a value (`sql`)?  Two very different things.

Comment: Take a look at `Futures`

Answer (score 2):

A thread is not a thing that can return a value.  A thread is a path of execution through your code.  Every program has a main thread that begins and ends somewhere in the internals of the JVM, and it can create other threads by use of Thread objects.

A thread that is created by a Thread object does nothing more or less than call the run() method of some Runnable object (possibly the Thread object itself, but that's an old-fashioned way of doing it.)  Since Runnable.run() does not return a value, there is no way for a thread to "return" a value.

Of course, your run() method could *store* a value in some field---a field of its own, or a field in some other object that it knows about.

The "Future" interface that Dgrin91 mentioned holds a value that was stored by a thread.  It's part of the java.util.concurrent package.  You use a java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService to manage a pool of worker threads, and you feed it "tasks" (a.k.a., Callables) to be performed.  A task *can* return a value.  You immediately get back a Future object each time you submit a task, and when some thread from the thread pool finally completes the task; it stores the return value in the Future, and then it *notifies* the Future.  The Future interface provides methods that you can call test whether the task has been completed, to *wait* for the task to be completed, and to get the value that the task returned.